# moving user to another page by entering correct password using php

Tags: php

i have a log in page. I want that when the user enters the correct username and password the the page he want open for him. and if the password and username wasn't correct he receive an error in the current page.
and another problem is that when you open the page first, you have an PHP undefined index error.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="post">
       <div class="data">
       <label for="name">username: </label>
          <input type="text" name="UserName"/>
       </div>
       <div class="data">
       <label for="name">password: </label>
          <input type="password" name="PassWord"/>
       </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="submit" id="submit"/>
<?php
$dbUserName = "alex";
$dbPassWord = "1234";
 $UserName = $_POST["UserName"];
 $PassWord = $_POST["PassWord"];
 if($UserName = $dbUserName&&$PassWord = $dbPassWord){
    //the code which moves the user to another page.
 }else echo "please enter the correct username and password";
?>
   </form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried header('location:');?

Comment: hint: use `===` instead of `=`. Also try to check the variables by using something like `isset()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move your PHP code to the beginning of your file to do it serverside (which would be the right thing to do) to avoid errors with output before setting headers. Additionally, your condition is assigning variable values (=) instead of comparing values (==).

An (untested) example of a setup that could work:

```
<?php
$dbUserName = "alex";
$dbPassWord = "1234";

if(isset($_POST['UserName']))
{
    $UserName = $_POST["UserName"];
    $PassWord = $_POST["PassWord"];

    if($UserName == $dbUserName && $PassWord == $dbPassWord)
    {
        header("Location: http://example.com/the/page/where/your/user/should/end/up");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
      $error = true;
    }
} 
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="post">
       <div class="data">
       <label for="name">username: </label>
          <input type="text" name="UserName"/>
       </div>
       <div class="data">
       <label for="name">password: </label>
          <input type="password" name="PassWord"/>
       </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
<?php if(isset($error)): ?>
please enter the correct username and password
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your if statement you accidentally put single '=' character when it should be double:

```
if($UserName == $dbUserName&&$PassWord == $dbPassWord){
```

Comment: Repox gave a more completed answer. Thanks anyway +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
<?php
$dbUserName = "alex";
$dbPassWord = "1234";
if (isset($_POST["UserName"]) && isset($_POST["PassWord"])) {
   $UserName = $_POST["UserName"];
   $PassWord = $_POST["PassWord"];
   if($UserName == $dbUserName && $PassWord == $dbPassWord){
      header('location:path/location');
      exit;
   } else echo "please enter the correct username and password";
}
?>
```

the `Undefined index` error is coming because `UserName` & `password` will not be present there till the form has been posted. so added the checks.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Also i would like to note that it is best to do the database query inside the if statement.

Comment: we must always add the checks properly. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case `=` is the operator to set a value to a variable (assignment operator).

With `==` and `===` you make a condition and check a value.

```
if($UserName == $dbUserName&&$PassWord == $dbPassWord) {
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

Like the other said, use `==` instead of `=`.

For your question about the redirection, see Repox answer.

Comment: This will give an error regarding setting headers after you made output.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($UserName == $dbUserName && $PassWord == $dbPassWord){
```

As phansen said, you are actually using the **assignment operator**, which will always equate to true.